# Automation tool in intelliJ

Tags: java, automation

I look for a good manner to automate my project. I have a project with many steps. In every steps output files are generated and compared with other files. Until know I wrote for each step a mainfunction that I have to let run in a certain order, because first I just needed the intermediate result. I know my project structure is not well planned. Is there a smart way to write a function, that run all the main-functions of the project in the correct order? Something like a `Makefile` in intelliJ?

My code works correctly but it is very bad structured and for a strange person not handy. I want to make it more handy without changing my code to much.

Comment: This sounds like a mess, but you can create some kind of supermain which would execute the main methods of other classes in desired order.

Comment: Traditionally the answer here would have been [Ant](https://ant.apache.org/) or [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/), but these days [Gradle](https://gradle.org/) is becoming the preferred build tool for Java projects. All of these tools have integrations with IntelliJ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to create some ant/maven build configuration. `main` is a static method just like any other. So you can simply create a class which would call the main methods of other classes

```
public class YourSuperClass{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        YourClass1.main(null); //You can provide String[] args instead of null
        YourClass2.main(null);
        YourClass3.main(null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class c2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/chromedrive/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    enter code here
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).